# Would the Timertask class be appropriate?

Tags: java

I'm working on a code and I need to add a timer to it..The function of the timer being that the code runs until a specified time has elapsed(e.g the code runs until 5mins has elapsed)..

Answer (score 0):

That's not what `TimerTask` does. If you want to stop your own code from running after X seconds, you'll need to periodically check to see how long your code has been running and *stop it yourself*.

Something like this:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long stopAfterMs = 5 * 60 * 1000; // 5-minute "timeout"
for(Element e : listOfElements) {
    performSomeOperation();

    if((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) > stopAfterMs)
        break; // time's up; exit the loop
}
```